# error in javascript or no clue

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I got the following javascript code.
And Basically, it works on FF, and IE with developer Tools.

```
$(function(){
    console.log("it is ok");
    var mybutton="";

    alert("ready1");
    $('button[name="delorder"]').click(function(){

        console.log($(this).val()+"hay i got a click");
        mybutton=$(this).val();
        alert("a click1");
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'deleteorderitem.php',
            data:mybutton,
            success:function(result){

                if((result.indexOf("t") < 3) && (result.indexOf("t") >= 0)){                    

                    $('#orderresult').html(result);                 

                    console.log("i am 3 ");
                    console.log("index of t is "+result.indexOf("t"));
                }else{
                    console.log("i am 4");                      
                    console.log("index of t is "+result.indexOf("t"));
                    $('#divOrderButton').hide();
                    $('#orderresult').html("");
                    $('#divNoinfo').html("There is no record to display at the moment.");
                    $('#divNoinfo').show(); 
                    $('#divOrder').hide();
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

But , it does NOT WORK on IE (without developer tools).
so, any advice will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What's the output in IE? Do you get any alert?

Comment: What is the error?  How does it not work?

Comment: console.log("it is ok"); is only available with developer tools window

Comment: alert("ready1");

does not show up and when i click on the button again 

alert("a click1"); does not turn up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is mostly because of

```
console.log()
```

Windows IE8 and below has no console object when the Developer tools is not open.

Either comment out the lines that says console. Or create the console object beforehand.

Try this ... Not sure if this is the correct way around..

```
var alertFallback = true;
   if (typeof console === "undefined" || typeof console.log === "undefined") {
     console = {};
     if (alertFallback) {
         console.log = function(msg) {
              alert(msg);
         };
     } else {
         console.log = function() {};
     }
   }
```

This will create  the console object if it is not present.

Comment: yes, Sushanth is RIGHT.

I got it when I comment out the console.log.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're saying it doesn't work without developer tools open, (unless I'm mistaken) it is because you have all those `console.log`'s and that must be what's blowing it up.

Try something like this at the very top of a master JS file to prevent that in IE.

```
if (typeof (console) === 'undefined' || !console) {
    window.console = {};
    window.console.log = function () { return; };
}
```

Comment: yes, again..

it is true that console.log is giving me headache. Thanks

Comment: Always is! I add this rule in the JS just in case a developer leaves a log in there, so it doesn't break in production!

Answer (score 0):

I use this function to write logs for cross browser console log :

```
/**
 *Log into the console if defined 
 */
function log(msg)
{       
    if (typeof console != "undefined") {
        console.log(msg);
    }       
}
```